# Temporarily increase log4j2 logger level in multi-threaded service

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j2

Here is a long question for you Log4j2 gurus.

I have a service that:

1. has very strict performance requirements
2. is instrumented with a lot of logging calls using log4j2.

A typical call is gated, like:

```
if ( LOG.isInfoEnabled() ) {
  LOG.info("everything's fine"); 
}
```

Because of the number of log messages and the performance needs, the service will generally run with logging set to WARN (i.e., not many messages).

However, I have been asked to build in a parameter to the service call that, if given, will cause it to:

1. Temporarily increase the logging level to whatever was requested in the parameter (e.g., INFO or TRACE)
2. Add a `WriterAppender` to capture the logging in a `PrintWriter`.
3. Append the `PrintWriter` log data to the request response.

It seems clear, due to the gating I put around each logging call, that I need to actually increase the logging level temporarily, like this:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration cfg = ctx.getConfiguration();
LoggerConfig loggerCfg = cfg.getLoggerConfig("com.mycompany.scm");
loggerCfg.setLevel(logLevel);
.. other code to add `WriterAppender` ...
ctx.updateLoggers();
```

But I have an immediate problem with that, in that it causes the logging to ALSO go the log file of the service.  That might not be the end of the world, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

I did that by having the default logging go through appenders that filter by level, so that even if logging is turned on, it won't write any messages more detailed than are wanted in the default log file.  (Like this, from my .properties file):

```
appenders=scm_warn, scm_info 

appender.scm_warn.type = Console
appender.scm_warn.name = SCM_WARN
appender.scm_warn.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.scm_warn.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.scm_warn.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.scm_warn.filter.threshold.level = warn

appender.scm_info.type = Console
appender.scm_info.name = SCM_INFO
appender.scm_info.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.scm_info.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.scm_info.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.scm_info.filter.threshold.level = info

loggers = coreConfigurator

logger.coreConfigurator.name = com.mycompany.scm
logger.coreConfigurator.level = warn
logger.coreConfigurator.additivity = false   # do not let configurator log messages get processed by client application's parent or root logger.
logger.coreConfigurator.appenderRefs = core
logger.coreConfigurator.appenderRef.core.ref = SCM_WARN
```

... that way, even if the logging level gets increased, the extra messages will not go to the main log file (I only want them to go to my `PrintWriter`).

**And now, the question!**

How can I temporarily increase the log level (like I try to do in the code above) for the current thread only?

If there are three (3) simultaneous calls to the service, I...

1. ... want each added `Appender` to only write log messages generated by the thread that created the `Appender`.
2. ... want each added `Appender` to be removed after the request that added it finishes.
3. ... want the logging level to get reset back to what it was, as long as there are no other requests with this logging parameter turned on still in process.

Ideally, I think it sounds like I want each thread to have a completely separate logging context.  Is that possible?  Any thoughts on how to do all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use a custom [Context Selector](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/manual/logsep.html) to have a different context per thread, but that's probably cause issues when multiple threads want to write to the same log file, so likely not a viable option.

The alternative is to write a custom `Appender`, that uses a `ThreadLocal` to store the `StringWriter`. If a `StringWriter` has not been established for the thread, the appended will skip logging. This custom `Appender` should be added in the Log4J config file, so it's always there and receiving log entries.

That way you enable logging for a particular thread by creating and assigning a `StringWriter` to the `ThreadLocal`, run the code, then clear the `ThreadLocal` and get the logged information from the `StringWriter`. Since there initially is no `StringWriter` for any thread, the appender will do nothing, so shouldn't affect performance in any noticeable way.

You'd still have to do the level-escalation you're already doing, with filters on the other appenders.

Comment: The customer `Appender` sounds very promising and I know just how to do it.  But what about the level escalation and de-escalation?  I still need to push the level up temporarily, or else the custom `Appender` won't even get any log messages.  I cannot keep the log level up all the time, or else I'll waste a lot of execution time building strings that don't go anywhere.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak As I said at the end, you still need to do that.

Comment: But is there a way to set the level up only for a given thread?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak No

Comment: The custom `Appender` idea worked beautifully!  It solved the problem of having to create, attach and detach multiple `WriterAppender`s on the fly.  Thanks a million!  Or, if not a million, 25 anyway (rep).

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- access to class logger and change the log level (as you suggested):
  `LogManager.getLogger(Class.forName("your.class.package")).setLevel(Level.FATAL);`
- use a different logger; just configure two different loggers.

Comment: I started out trying to add a new logger programmatically, but it did not work.  Nothing got logged to it.  I expect that there was a problem with having 2 loggers for `com.mycompany.scm`.  If you could elaborate on how to make your thoughts work, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Right now I’m away ahahah; anyway, you should define two static logger with two different Appenders and the same package, but different log level (if you want you could also use a different log file - this conf should be made on the log4j file). The you’ve just to call a logger or another. Look at https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-custom-appender

Comment: "Then you've just to call a logger or another".  That means I need to touch every log message in my code?

Comment: Not everywhere, but where you need it

Comment: I need it everywhere.  Thanks anyway.